# Hot to change install version in install jammer from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, installation

I am trying to write a bat file for auto build generation. Could somebody please tell me how to change the install version and the version string from command line in install jammer? I am using below code for creating build. It runs well but now I need to change its install version and version string. how can I do this?

```
C:\Program Files<x86>\installjammer\installjammer --output-dir D:\Sumeet --build D:\AgnisysProjects\My InstallJammer Projects\Install jammer project\IDesignSpecExcel2007\IDesignSpecExcel2007.mpi
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got solution

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallJammer> installjammer -DVersion 5.16.34.0 -DInstallVersion 5.16.34.0 --output-dir D:\Sumeet --build-for-release D:\AgnisysProjects\My InstallJammer Projects\Install jammer project\IDesignSpecExcel2007\IDesignSpecExcel2007.mpi
```